# Recreating a dataframe by using conditions from two different columns

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a massive dataframe seems like this:

```
df = data.frame(year = c(rep(1998,5),rep(1999,5)), 
                  loc = c(10,rep(14,4),rep(10,2),rep(14,3)),
                  sitA = c(rep(0,3),1,1,0,1,0,1,1),
                  sitB = c(1,0,1,0,1,rep(0,4),1),
                  n = c(2,13,2,9,4,7,2,7,7,4))
df
   year loc sitA sitB  n
1  1998  10    0    1  2
2  1998  14    0    0 13
3  1998  14    0    1  2
4  1998  14    1    0  9
5  1998  14    1    1  4
6  1999  10    0    0  7
7  1999  10    1    0  2
8  1999  14    0    0  7
9  1999  14    1    0  7
10 1999  14    1    1  4
```

As you can see, there are years, localities, two different situation (denoted as `sitA` and `sitB`) and finally the counts of these records (column `n`).

I wanted to create a new data frame which reflects the counts for only year and localities where counts for situation A and B stored in the columns conditionally such as desired output below:

```
df.new
  year loc sitB.0.sitA.0 sitB.0.sitA.1 sitB.1.sitA.0 sitB.1.sitA.1
1 1998  10             0             0             2             0
2 1998  14            13             9             2             4
3 1999  10             7             2             0             0
4 1999  14             7             7             0             4
```

The tricky part as you can realize is that the original dataframe doesn't include all of the conditions. It only has the ones where the count is above 0. So the new dataframe should have "0" for the missing conditions in the original dataframe. Therefore, well known functions such as melt (reshape) or aggregate failed to solve my issue. A little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `tidyverse` method, we first append the column names to the values for `sit..` columns. Then we `unite` and combine them into one column and finaly `spread` the values.

```
library(tidyverse) 
df[3:4] <- lapply(names(df)[3:4], function(x) paste(x, df[, x], sep = "."))

df %>%
  unite(key, sitA, sitB, sep = ".") %>%
  spread(key, n, fill = 0)

#  year loc sitA.0.sitB.0 sitA.0.sitB.1 sitA.1.sitB.0 sitA.1.sitB.1
#1 1998  10             0             2             0             0
#2 1998  14            13             2             9             4
#3 1999  10             7             0             2             0
#4 1999  14             7             0             7             4
```

If the position of the columns is not fixed you can use `grep` first

```
cols <- grep("^sit", names(df))
df[cols] <- lapply(names(df)[cols], function(x) paste(x, df[, x], sep = "."))
```